# UIbutton not updating its tag value in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uibutton, xcode4.5

I have a tableview in which I m loading some UIButtons and giving them dynamic tags.But tag=0 is not updated for UIButton. I couldn't understand wheres the mistake...

```
int i=-1;
    @synthesize......

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     btnTemp = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,lblName.frame.origin.y+lblName.frame.size.height+3,17, 17)];     
     [btnTemp addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     btnTemp.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [btnTemp setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     btnTemp.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];
     btnTemp.tag=++i;
     return cell;

}
```

But for the fist time it goes into this method UIButtons tag value is not getting updated to 0.

```
-(IBAction) btnClicked:(UIButton *) sender{


    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%d", [button tag]);
    UIButton  *btnTemp = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:0]; //Here UIButton is being converted to UItableViewCell  and getting error.
   [buttonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp];
}
```

Where I m going wrong..?

Comment: Set the button tag using `indexPath.row`. How is that not helping in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void) btnClicked:(UIButton *) sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d", [sender tag]);
    [buttonsinaSection addObject:sender];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     btnTemp = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,lblName.frame.origin.y+lblName.frame.size.height+3,17, 17)];     
     [btnTemp addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     btnTemp.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [btnTemp setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     btnTemp.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];
     btnTemp.tag=indexpath.row;
     return cell;

}
```

**Hey, in btnClicked action again you are taking the ViewWithTag:0.. So, By Default on View, every object will have as an tag = 0.. So, you will get the button instance in your btnClicked where in this (UIButton *) says**

Comment: I gave it as btnTemp.tag=indexpath.row;but even now if indexpath.row is 0 btnTemp value is not gtng updated to 0?What elz can I do ?

Comment: once have a breakpoint at btnClicked and can you pls paste the sender.tag.. which i had edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `tag` is 0.  That means that every view in your view hierarchy has a `tag` of 0 unless something changes it.  This includes your `UITableView` and every `UITableViewCell` in that table view.  So, for example, when you call `[cell viewWithTag:0]` on a `UITableViewCell`, the cell will return itself unless you've changed the cell's `tag` to something other than 0.

It is simply infeasible to try to use `tag` value 0 to find a particular button, or any other view, unless you have very close control of the view hierarchy.  If you're using `UITableView` or `UITableViewCell`, you don't have enough control, because each of those views has private subviews that may well have `tag` values of 0.

Comment: U mean I couldn't view UIbutton of tag 0?If such is the case then can I assign separate tag value to UItableViewCell?Because I need UIbutton with tag value as zero only ...Otherwise how can I compare if it is a UItableViewCell or not?

Answer (score 0):

when you write:

```
 btnTemp.tag=++i;
```

for every cell btnTemp's tag becomes 0.

So you should write:

```
 btnTemp.tag=indexPath.row;
```

and,

```
 UIButton  *btnTemp = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:0];
```

will give you error, because `[cell viewWithTag:0]` method cannot be called outside of **cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
-(void) btnClicked:(UIButton *) sender
{
  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
  [buttonsinaSection addObject:button];
}
```